# Can I use StringBuilder elements in a foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, foreach, stringbuilder

Since I'm using .NET 1.1, I can't use a generic List of string, as generics were not part of the language yet. So I'm trying to use a StringBuilder, but get this err msg:

*"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' because 'System.Text.StringBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible"*

with this code:

```
public StringBuilder linesToSend;
. . .

foreach (string _line in this.linesToSend)
{
    serialPort.Write(_line);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or is StringBuilder really disallowed from foreach loops? If the latter, is String[] my best recourse?

Comment: try using a List<string> or ArrayList instead Clay

Comment: Note: In 1.1, you can use [System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx) in lieu of the missing List<string>.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: As mentioned, generics are not available in .NET 1.1

Comment: Clay I mentioned or `ArrayList` as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `StringBuilder` doesn't store the lines that you append. It simply is used to build the final string. Assuming you've added everything to the `StringBuilder` already, you can do:

```
// Write the complete string to the serialPort
serialPort.Write(linesToSend.ToString());
```

Answer (score 6):

Old question, I know, but something potentially useful:

If each of your strings were built with .AppendLine or you inserted a new line, you can do

```
string[] delim = { Environment.NewLine, "\n" }; // "\n" added in case you manually appended a newline
string[] lines = StringBuilder.ToString().Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach(string line in lines){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is correct. A `StringBuilder` is designed to help you build one final output string as the others have stated.

If you have a variable number of strings you need to work on, you can use an `ArrayList` and iterate over that.

```
ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();
// populate the list
foreach (string str in strings) {
  // do what you need to.
}
```

If you're afraid that the array list might contain other objects (as it isn't strongly typed) you can cast it safely instead:

```
foreach (object obj in strings) {
  string str = obj as string;
  // If null strings aren't allowed, you can use the following
  // to skip to the next element.
  if (str == null) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `StringBuilder` is building just **one** string, so how could you `foreach` it to get a whole sequence of strings?

If you need to write line by line, maybe use an `ArrayList`, add each line string to that, and `foreach` with `string` as the `foreach` variable type (`Object` will be cast to `String`). Or even better, use [`StringCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (thank to comment by Anthony Pegram, to the original question; I had forgotten this class).

But why not upgrade to a newer version of .NET?

Comment: For this project, I can't upgrade. In other project, I AM using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 and VS 2012 on Windows 8, but this project will remain in VS 2003 / .NET 1.1

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` loop works by calling the `GetEnumerator` from the interface `IEnumerable` which will return an enumerator that `foreach` uses to get the next element of the object.

`StringBuilder` does not implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` which would allow the `foreach` to work. You are better off using a `string[]` or `StringCollection` in this case and when you are done you can concatenate the collection using a `StringBuilder`.

ex:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string line in array)
{
    serialPort.Write(line);
    stringBuilder.Append(line);
}
```

Comment: The `foreach` loop actually duck-types its operand.  If the operand has a method called `GetEnumerator` whose return type includes a parameterless method called `MoveNext` that returns `bool`, and a readable property named `Current` that returns the control-variable type, then `foreach` will use without regard for whether the type implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` [if the type explicitly implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but defines a `GetEnumerator` method separate from the interface, a `foreach` loop will use the latter].

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an array of strings if you know the number of elements, or else a dictionary.

Comment: It is mutable, i.e. you don't have to indicate the number of items you're going to put into it beforehand. Although, I meant Collection rather than Dictionary. sorry.